# Zxing is not supoorting this qr code. Its not able to scan the qr code

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, zxing, zxing.net

I have implemented the Zxing but it does not scans with this qr code. Can anyone please suggest how to go for it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8l7zB.png)

This is the code for the viewmodel that I have used.-

private async void OnIndicatorScreenUsingScanClicked(object obj)
{

```
        ZXingScannerPage scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
       
       
        scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
        {
            Con = result.Text;

            scanPage.IsScanning = true;

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                await (Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PopAsync();
                await OnIndicatorScreenClicked("");
            });
        };
        await (Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage).Detail.Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any reader that can read it?

Comment: Please share part of your own work to solve the problem first.

Comment: that does not appear to be a standard QR code

Comment: @GSerg it works with any scanner that I download with Playstore . it doesn't work with the Zxing

Comment: @Kiyarash I am attaching that too

Comment: @Jason We have modified the qr code but it works with all other qr code scanner in playstore but not with zxing.